# Trouble in installing ubuntu touch on samsung galaxy grand neo

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have been trying to install ubuntu touch on my phone but the terminal shows no change for hours. HELP!!

```
ronak@iron2:~$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
2015/09/06 19:25:16 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
```